# Problem in putting a download button to download a pdf file in a React Website

Tags: reactjs, download

I'm creating a portfolio website using react and I want to add the feature of adding a download button in it so that anyone could download my resume through the portfolio site.

```
 <Link to="Resume.pdf" download>Download</Link>
```

I put the above code for it but it doesn't download my resume. Can I get some ways that I could make it work?

Comment: So what does it do instead? Display a 404 not found page? Or opened a PDF viewer on the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Lets consider that your resume.pdf file is present in a same folder. You can import the file and pass it as a variable.

```
import resume from './Resume.pdf';

<Link to={resume} download>Download</Link>
```